# How to read from a json file in a test module shared with other modules?

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle-kotlin-dsl

To read from a json file in `resources` folder of `test` folder, i use

```
sourceSets {

    val sharedTestDir = "src/test-shared/java"

    getByName("test") {
        java.srcDir(sharedTestDir)
    }

    getByName("androidTest") {
        java.srcDir(sharedTestDir)
        resources.srcDir("src/test/resources")
    }
}
```

and in test-shared folder i use extension functions to convert json file to objects

```
fun getResourceAsText(path: String): String {
    return object {}.javaClass.classLoader!!.getResource(path)!!.readText()
}

inline fun <reified T> convertToObjectFromString(input: String): T? {
    return Gson().fromJsonWithType<T>(input)
}

inline fun <reified T> Gson.fromJsonWithType(json: String): T? =
    fromJson<T>(json, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
```

I created a test module, `test-utils`, to be used in other modules to prevent same boilerplate code.

The issue i saw examining the other projects i saw you don't add dependencies to this module using `testImplementation` or `androidTestImplementation`, instead you put files to `main`  folder instead of `test-shared` folder, and use `implementation` and add this module to other modules using `testImplementation(project(".."))`, if you use `testImplementation` instead of `implementation` you get **unresolved reference** error from tests, for instance in `data` module.

Dependencies in `test-utils` module build.gradle.kts

```
dependencies {

    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))

    implementation(Deps.KOTLIN)
    implementation(Deps.ANDROIDX_CORE_KTX)
    implementation(Deps.RX_JAVA)
    implementation(Deps.RX_ANDRIOD)
    implementation(Deps.COROUTINES_CORE)
    implementation(Deps.COROUTINES_ANDROID)

    implementation(TestDeps.ANDROIDX_CORE_KTX)
    implementation(TestDeps.ANDROIDX_CORE_TESTING)

    implementation(Deps.GSON)
}
```

Add `test-utils` module as project to `data` module with

```
testImplementation(project(Modules.AndroidLibrary.TEST_UTILS))
```

However, with this approach i cannot read from the json file located in `resources` folder inside `test` folder and get null pointer exception. Also, can't use `assets` folder either since this file is required in unit tests? Is there anyway to add json file without putting it inside resources folder in every module?